# How to get model from Partial View in MVC

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, controller

I have a main Index view from which I call view called Create, into which I pass type of the widget I want to create as a string.

Index view:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "WidgetEditor", new { wType = "image" })"><i class="fa fa-image"></i> Create Image Widget</a> - 
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "WidgetEditor", new { wType = "text"  })"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> Create Text Widget</a>
```

Create Action:

```
public ActionResult Create(string wType)
{
    ViewBag.wType = wType;
    return View();
}
```

the type is then passed into view via ViewBag.wType and this is evaluated in the Create View

Create view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <section class="row">
    @{
        if (ViewBag.wType == "image")
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/WidgetEditor/_CreateImageWidget.cshtml");
        }
        else if (ViewBag.wType == "text")
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/WidgetEditor/_CreateTextWidget.cshtml");
        }
    }
    </section>
}
```

and depending on this, appropriate partial view is loaded.
Partial views have different models so when the form is submitted, I do not know how which model is passed back. The one from _CreateImageWidget or _CreateTextWidget.

If the HttpPost controller look like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(DisplayWidgetImageViewModel imageModel, DisplayWidgetTextViewModel textModel)
{
    return new ViewResult();
}
```

I will get populated imageModel if _CreateImageWidget partial is chosen and textMode if _CreateTextWidget partial is chosen.

This is acceptable it the number of widgets types does not change, but this is not the case.
Is there a way to get somehow specific model from a partial view and know/find out which one it is or am I doing this completely wrong way?

Comment: there is a similiar problem with solution which is looking promissing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922339/determine-the-model-of-a-partial-view-from-the-controller-within-mvc?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this answer to solve my problem: [determine-the-model-of-a-partial-view-from-the-controller-within-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922339/determine-the-model-of-a-partial-view-from-the-controller-within-mvc?rq=1)

there are also several other link with more resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple forms in single page. You can also use different action methods per partial:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")) {
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/WidgetEditor/_CreateImageWidget.cshtml")
}
```

You all this without having to use Ajax.

Comment: it is a step forward, but still if there is 20 widgets, I will end up with 20 forms ... although if the form is a part of partial view ... but I will still have a lot of actions ...

Comment: Unfortunately the default binder has to know the explicit type. One other thing your could do is setup a custom binder. The custom binder could act on a parent type or class. This way you only use one Action.